# Solving a complex algebraic formula with java

Tags: java, algebra

I am trying to solve for y in the following equation using Java:

[image]

For the sake of visibility I divided the numerator and denominator into separate variables. I need to compute for `x = -3` through `x = 4` moving in increments of `0.5`.

```
for(double x = -3; x <= 4; x += .5)
{
    // Now we compute the formula for all values in between -3 and 4 in increments of 0.5

    double top = ( 9 * Math.pow(x, 3) ) - ( 27 * Math.pow(x, 2) ) - ( (4 * x) + 12 );
    double bottom = ( Math.pow(( 3 * Math.pow(x, 2) + 1 ) , 1/2) + Math.abs( 5 - (Math.pow(x, 4)) ) );

    double y = top / bottom;

    System.out.print("X = " + x + "\t Y = " + y);
}
```

The values I get are not as intended.

```
X = -3.0     Y = -6.311688311688312 
X = -2.5     Y = -8.880570409982175   
X = -2.0     Y = -15.333333333333334      
X = -1.5     Y = -91.41176470588235 
X = -1.0     Y = -8.8   
X = -0.5     Y = -3.0105263157894737 
X = 0.0      Y = -2.0   
X = 0.5      Y = -3.305263157894737   
X = 1.0      Y = -6.8    
X = 1.5      Y = -45.529411764705884     
X = 2.0      Y = -4.666666666666667  
X = 2.5      Y = -1.429590017825312  
X = 3.0      Y = -0.3116883116883117    
X = 3.5      Y = 0.19940094137783482     
X = 4.0      Y = 0.4603174603174603
```

Using an online tool I computed for X = 0 and got 2 instead of -2. Is there something wrong with how I did the math?

Comment: You will find that 1/2 = 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You made a mistake while implementing the expression.

```
... - ( (4 * x) + 12 )
```

Should be

```
... - (4 * x) + 12
```

Or in the complete expression:

```
double top = ( 9 * Math.pow(x, 3) ) - ( 27 * Math.pow(x, 2) ) - (4 * x) + 12;
```

Also as noted by [@JacobG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50688364/4668606):

`1/2` evaluates to 0, since it's an integer-division. This doesn't make any difference if you evaluate the for `x = 0` though. This can be corrected using `0.5` instead.

Comment: That solved is correctly for x = 0 however still not for the other values such as ``x = -2.5`` which is supposed to equal ``−7.463007``. Thanks.

Comment: @davidxd33 Just updated my answer. There's actually another mistake, noticed in [JacobG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50688364/4668606)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help, I got it.

Comment: @ifly6 Correct. But you forgot the minus. `- ( (4 * x) + 12 )` is the complete expression that needs to be corrected. I'll update the answer. With the minus it does make a difference

Answer (score 6):

There's a small typo in your equation:

```
1/2
```

Is equal to `0` in Java; see: [Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

To fix this, you can just type `0.5`, or use `1 / 2D` or `1D / 2`.

See [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50688356/7294647) for another issue with your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the problem along with Paul's answer. You have no idea how much of a headache this was.